# MongoDB ReplicaSet on windows azure - Sockect exception error

Tags: mongodb, azure

I have 3 node replica set deployed in windows azure. While doing performance testing, the test code halts after sometime. In the server I can see the following error log -
Fri Aug 30 23:14:59.982 [conn2454] SocketException handling request, closing client connection: 9001 socket exception [SEND_ERROR] server [ip:port]
For the performance test I am using multithreaded code to only read data from the replicaset. 
So far I have tried http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/#does-tcp-keepalive-time-affect-sharded-clusters-and-replica-sets. But it did not help so far.
Any thoughts/suggestions will be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but just in case someone else stumbles across this.

You need to set the TCP/IP keep alive times different from the stock Linux configuration if you are running under Azure:

```
echo 45 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time   
echo 30 >  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl   
echo 20 >  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
```